# How to display image in Krypton Button

Tags: winforms, krypton-toolkit

In my existing system Krypton button is been used. I want to display image instead of text in the button. My current Buttonstyle is set as "LowProfile". I am confused about the button style mode in tool kit also. I couldnt find any relevant documents for the ButtonStyle.

So my questions are:

1. Where can I find the good document/tutorial for the krypton tool kit?
2. How to display image in the krypton Button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image can be added in StateCommon -> Back -> Image -> {Select your image}
Also to visualize the image set **Draw to True**

Answer (score 0):

Krypton is now open source.
https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton

You can find some examples of KryptonButton in the KryptonExplorer.exe and KryptonButtonExamples.exe demo projects.

Source code for these projects are available here:
https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton/tree/master/Source/Krypton%20Toolkit%20Examples

In these projects, the image is added with Properties, Values, Image, {Select your image}

Otherwise, you can also use: Properties, StateCommon, Back, Image, {Select your image}

The difference between Values and StateCommon seems to be "some padding" and therefore the image is not directly on the border/edge of the button.